# display jquery returned data correctly

Tags: jquery, html, post

i've been a prototype user for a few years, and now for several reasons, i'm moving to jquery.. but still have yet familiarize myself with jquery's syntax.. my question is

how do I convert this prototype code to jquery correctly?

```
new Ajax.Updater('displayArea', 'shoutbox.php', { method:'post',
    parameters: {action: 'display', some_data: some_data}
});
```

and here's what i did:

```
$.post("shoutbox.php", {action: "display", some_data: some_data}, function(data){$("#displayArea").text(data);},"html");
```

i got the exact return result from jquery and prototype, but the problem is, when jquery updates the "displayArea", it's not quite what I expected. the returned data has some html codes in it, and instead of displaying a new line for the html tag 'br', jquery just display the 'br' in plain text. what i means is it's displaying html codes, and that's not what I want. hope you all get what i meant....

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`jQuery.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method as its name implies, is used to insert a text, not HTML code. Use [`jQuery.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead.

```
$("#displayArea").html(data);
```